# Unity 4.6 Scroll Rect, Mark problems

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mask, scrollrect

I have project using unity 4.6 canvas, panel and button. I want display list button like this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue6gNUWOM-w it worked with many device and unity IDE

[image]

but when I play this in my phone Mobiistar Touch S01, Android version 2.3.6. It not worked

[image]

Sorry about my english! Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Is it scrolling on your phone? If yes, then it should work,  check if anchors settings

Comment: thank for reply! yes, it work, but size too small, in unity ide and another device it show 6 button but my phone it show only 1 button

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLt_Y3Hw1v3QTEbh8fQV1DUOUIh9nF0k6c check this tutoral series